# mysql_safe: command not found CentOS 7

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, centos

I just installed Cent OS 7, and want to start learning Laravel. But immediately faced a problem with MySql. It asks me for a password which I didnt set. By default it should be empty, but it is not working for me. So I am trying to recover root password, using mysql_safe. But getting this error:

```
        bash: mysql_safe: command not found...
```

I looked to the bin directory and didnt found this file.

```
        yum install mysql-server
```

says that mysql is already installed and up to date.
Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is called mysql**d**_save. More can be found here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqld-safe.html